# Does Proguard obfuscate library projects used by an app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

First, let me emphasize that I am **not** talking about obfuscating library projects independently or obfuscating library jars.

Suppose an Android app FooApp has a library project FooLib in its build path (please note it is a project, not a jar in Eclipse).  Is FooLib obfuscated when FooApp is obfuscated by ProGuard?

I have configured FooLib to use ProGuard, but such configuration does not seem to do anything.

Comment: yes, afaik does proguard objusticate libs, I ran in a few problems where some crappy advertiser used reflection...

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.  Though ProGuard does not generate the ProGuard fodler in the library project with files such as mapping.txt, it does appear to obfuscate the library because I checked the mapping.txt of the app project and found the classes of the library.  Could you turn your comment as the answer so I can accept it?